# How do I reduce the line spacing between text in my Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, line, textview, spacing

I'd like to decrease the line spacing between the text (User12, 5 movies, 2.5% improved) in the attached layout.

[image]

Here's the xml below (I tried removing the singleLine="true" statement and tried setting it to false):

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="36dip"
    android:layout_height="36dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7.5">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreDesc"
        android:text="User12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreDesc"
        android:text="5 movies"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreDesc"
        android:text="2.5% improved"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreNum"
    android:text="32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="60dip"  
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 76):

Long time since the question was asked but if anyone needs an answer in the future this can be achieved simply by passing a negative value to

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="-4dp"
```

Comment: The question means between each component in the LinearLayout. This one works with just TextView. See my response below.

Comment: Negative value cut down the below line characters like "g" will be cut down from bottom.

Comment: It works and, from what I've seen, it doesn't cut lower parts of letters like "g" or "p".

Answer (score 10):

Setting lineSpacingMultiplier seems better in this case than lineSpacingExtra, e.g.

`android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"`

(This works if all your text is in a single TextView that has the above line in the xml.)

Answer (score 7):

As Cullan says above, you have to put a negative margin value:

**android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreDesc"
    android:text="User12"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreDesc"
    android:text="5 movies"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. None of the other ones worked.