# Reduce the space between lines in the textview android

Tags: android, textview

I have a Single `TextView` it has a text `Namanpeet Kaur commented on your item thread bangles`

[image]

---

How to reduce the spacing between the lines...

**Layout:**

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_description"
                    style="@style/chatMessageUserMsg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
                    android:textColor="@color/clr_txt_description"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Already tried: [padding between TextView lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines

Comment: **`android:lineSpacingExtra=""`**

Comment: @Amritkumar .. I did try the `lineSpacing extra` .... like ..... `android:lineSpacingExtra="-3dp"
                        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.5"` .... didn't resolve it ....is something i need to change

Comment: @Devrath can you share layout file

Comment: @NileshRathod .. I added the xml

Comment: This is default padding which TextView uses and can not solved by android:lineSpacingExtra. You need to try removing that default padding from TextView. I think that attribute is something like includeFontPadding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100351/how-do-i-reduce-the-line-spacing-between-text-in-my-android-layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
```

you can use the spacing according to your need.